# AWS SDK Working with DynamoDB and putItem won't allow me to insert without updating

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Here is how I am inserting an item into the database:

```
DynamoDB.putItemAsync({
    "TableName": tblName,
    "Item": {
        "UserId": { "S": String(obj.user_id) },
        "CampaignId": { "N": String(obj.campaign_id) },
        "Email": { "S": String(obj.email) },
        "CustomActivityNodeId": { "N": String(obj.custom_activity_node_id) }
    },
    "Expected": {
        "UserId": {
            "Exists": false
        }
    }
})
```

The `putItemAsync` call is because I `promisified` the library with `bluebird`. I tried doing this:

```
{
    "Expected": {
        "UserId": {
            "Exists": false
        }
    }
}
```

With my `putItem` call, but am having NO luck. All I want to do is insert records without existing ones updating

Comment: I am facing a similar issue did you solve this? Cheers

Answer (score 3):

From [PutItem API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a
>   conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function
>   with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the
>   table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the
>   attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item
>   exists.

First, make sure `UserId` is the PK of the table, then you could use `ConditionExpression` with `attribute_not_exists`:

```
DynamoDB.table('users').PutItem({}, {
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(email)"
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
    // [LOG] possible bug with time
})
```

That will create an Item **ONLY** if email (my pk in the table) not exist previously.

*PS: I'm using a [wrapper](https://github.com/frangeris/react-native-dynamodb) for dynamodb in react-native.*